# Denjoy-Wolff point for the identity function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Assume that $f(z)$ is a  non automorphism function defined on the unit disk. The Denjoy-Wolff point of $f(z)$ it is the unique point $w$ in the closure of the unit disk such that $w = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]}(z)$,  where $f^{[n]}(z) =  f(z) \circ f(z) \circ f(z) ..... \circ f(z)$ n-times.
I wonder how to find the Denjoy-Wolff point for $f(z) = z$ which is an automorphism function (I saw an article for Cowen that say the Denjoy-Wolff point of $f(z) = z$ is $w=0$). I know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]}(z) = z$, what do we mean by a point equal to z. How does he conclude that the point is zero ??

Comment: Denjoy-Wolff point is defined when $f$ is not an automorphism of $D$.

Comment: There is no such point for $f(z)=z$ of course, simply because $f^{[n]}(z)=z$ for all $z$ and all $n$, thus $\lim_nf^{[n]}(z)=z$ for all $z$, i.e. there is no single point $w$ of the disk with this property.